# How can I pick out the symmetric and antisymmetric parts of a tensor product of line bundles over projective space?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

If I have a vector bundle constructed as a direct sum of line bundles
$$
E = \mathcal{O}(a_1)\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathcal{O}(a_n)
$$
Is there any general method for picking out the symmetric and antisymmetric parts of a tensor bundle of $E$? For example, how can I find the decomposition of
\begin{align*}
\otimes^3(\mathcal{O}(a)\oplus\mathcal{O}(b)) &= \mathcal{O}(3a) \oplus \mathcal{O}(2a+b)^{\oplus 2} \oplus \mathcal{O}(a+2b)^{\oplus 2}\oplus\mathcal{O}(3b) \\
&= \text{Sym}^3(E) \oplus \Lambda^3 E
\end{align*}
in terms of line bundles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use formulas 
$$
S^n(E_1 \oplus E_2) = \bigoplus_{i=0}^n S^i(E_1) \otimes S^{n-i}(E_2),
\qquad
\Lambda^n(E_1 \oplus E_2) = \bigoplus_{i=0}^n \Lambda^i(E_1) \otimes \Lambda^{n-i}(E_2),
$$
and iterate them.

Comment: And since $\Lambda^2(\mathcal{O}(a)) = 0$, this allows one to readily compute the exterior powers of the line bundles.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding the formulas. If $E_1=\mathbb{R}$ and $E_2=\mathbb{R}$, does this mean that $S^2(\mathbb{R}^2) \simeq \mathbb{R}$? That's not right, so what am I missing?

Comment: @user505117: how did you apply the formula?

Comment: @Sasha Considering vector bundles over a point (i.e. vector spaces). Setting $E_1=\mathbb{R}$, $E_2=\mathbb{R}$, the left hand side of the formula is $S^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$. The right hand side is $S^0(\mathbb{R}) \otimes S^2(\mathbb{R}) \oplus  S^1(\mathbb{R}) \otimes S^1(\mathbb{R}) \oplus S^2(\mathbb{R}) \otimes S^0(\mathbb{R})$. We have $S^2(\mathbb{R})=0$, so the right hand side is $S^1(\mathbb{R}) \otimes S^1(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user505117: in fact, $S^2(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks, that clears that up.